# Programically update node when visited by 'editor' role

Tags: 7, hooks

My goal is to have *promote-node-when-visited-by-editor* feature. This is code from `MYMODULE` using `hook_node_view`:

```
function MYMODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
    // 'promote-node-when-visited-by-editor' (roles[6]) feature
    if ($node->type == 'blog') {
        if (empty($node->promote)) {
            if ($view_mode == 'full') {
                global $user;
                if (isset($user->roles[6])) {
                    $node_data = node_load($node->nid);
                    $node_data->promote = '1';
                    node_save($node_data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When all IFs are met, I get this error in execution part with hook_node_view:

```
Recoverable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to drupal_attributes()
must be of the type array, null given, called in /includes/common.inc
on line 2534 and defined in drupal_attributes() (line 2426
of /includes/common.inc).
```

What's the right hook when I want programically update node when (after, right before...) visited by `editor` role. For example rules have `content is viewed` event.

Comment: This is a somewhat odd workflow. Why can't editors control the publishing statuses? Or why not implement Workflow, Workbench, or Revisioning for stateful publishing?

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced these 3 lines

```
            $node_data = node_load($node->nid);
            $node_data->promote = '1';
            node_save($node_data);
```

with

```
            db_update('node')
                    ->fields(array(
                        'promote' => '1',
                    ))
                    ->condition('nid', $node->nid)
                    ->execute();
            db_update('node_revision')
                    ->fields(array(
                        'promote' => '1',
                    ))
                    ->condition('nid', $node->nid)
                    ->execute();
            db_query('DELETE FROM cache_entity_node WHERE cache_entity_node.cid = :nid', array ( ':nid' => $node->nid));
```

and it seems working :)

Comment: I would avoid this route because a direct db write means the rest of the system is unaware that the node was updated. This can have very funky results.

Comment: It is a really bad answer as you directly update the database without acknowledging the Drupal.

Comment: No, it's not 'really bad' because It perfectly fits with the rest of the site functionality. @Kevin's "I would avoid" answer is better. He would avoid, I would not. Anyway, thank you for your feedbacks.